# Randomly shows The remote name could not be resolved: "<hostname>" after deploying in azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, exception, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Our web api based app has lot of external service calls including keyvault and azure sql Database. After deploying in azure as appservice randomly it is getting lot of exception saying **"The remote name could not be resolved:"**. We are getting this exception for keyvault and other external call for which we used HttpClient.
For sql database we are getting exception **"The underlying provider failed on Open."** with innerexception **A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)",** In the local machine(IIS) it does not gets those exceptions and it occurs randomly. We are badly stucked with this. Anyone have any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Database this is possibly caused by a connection timeout.  You should increase the connection timeout to 30 seconds (can be set in the connection string or connection object) and you should include retry logic in your app.